# Initialize object with final instances dart

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have this class :

```
class Person {
  Person(
      @required this.name,
      @required this.age,
      @required this.job,
  });
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final String job;
  );
```

How can I create an object that has all these properties but set by me before the use? Something like :

```
Person william(name : 'William', age : 25, job : 'officer');
doSomething(william);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the code below :

```
   void main() {
      final Person william = Person(name:"William", age:25, job:"officer");
      doSomething(william);
    }
    
    void doSomething(Person person) {
      print('${person.name} ${person.age} ${person.job}');
    }
    
    class Person {
      Person({
        this.name,
        this.age,
        this.job,
      });
    
      final String name;
      final int age;
      final String job;
    }
```

Comment: @jamesdlin you are correct. OP & me, both made two edits, in my previous I did not use optional parameters which lead to my comment. I'll edit my description.